# Paging - multiple pages

Tags: operating-system, paging

I searched everywhere but I couldn’t find a real answer about this specific case.

Let’s say we have registered two pages with fragmented address (I mean they are not contiguous) in the same page directory, then registered directory address in CR3 and activated paging with CR0.

If a loaded program P1 loaded at 0x0 in the first page try to access an address higher than the max address of page 1, will it be automatically mapped to page 2 or do we need to setup an interruption ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If a loaded program P1 loaded at 0x0 in the first page try to access an address higher than the max address of page 1, will it be automatically mapped to page 2 or do we need to setup an interruption ?

Nothing is automatically mapped.

When you access anything at any virtual address, the CPU splits the virtual address into several pieces - e.g. an "index into page directory", and "index into page table" and an "offset in final page". Then it uses most of these pieces as indexes into various tables.

If something isn't present (if the page directory entry at "`page_directory[index_in_page_directory]`" says that the page table isn't present, or if if the page table entry at "`page_table[index_in_page_table]`" says that the page isn't present) then the CPU triggers a page fault exception.

The CPU also does other protection checks at the same time - e.g. for a write, if the page directory entry at "`page_directory[index_in_page_directory]`" says "read only" then you get a page fault for that too.

Of course the page fault handler can do all kinds of things, including "auto-mapping" a page that wasn't present and then returning to the instruction that caused the page fault (which will cause that instruction to be executed a second time with no problem because the page is mapped now).